# Getting "Relation does not exists" for existing Postgres view in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to map an existing PostgreSQL view (which creation script was ran and tested in a different computer) to a Rails application, but I keep getting `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "reports_consultants_clients_tasks" does not exist`.

First, this is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :reports do
  get 'consultants_clients_tasks/index'
  end
  # rest of the file
end
```

The controller:

```
class Reports::ConsultantsClientsTasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @consultants_clients_tasks = ConsultantsClientsTask.all
  end
end
```

The model (I tried with and without table name, anyway, it should be following the convention... right?)

```
class Reports::ConsultantsClientsTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  #self.table_name = "CONSULTANTS_CLIENTS_TASKS"
end
```

This is my migration to create the view:

```
class CreateReportsConsultantsClientsTasksSqlView < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    execute <<-SQL
      CREATE VIEW CONSULTANTS_CLIENTS_TASKS AS
      -- rest of the script
      ;
    SQL
  end
end
```

I tried running both `rake db:reset` or `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` and in both cases the view isn't properly created.

If I run this (the query generated by ActiveRecord), from a psql console:

```
SELECT "CONSULTANTS_CLIENTS_TASKS".* FROM "CONSULTANTS_CLIENTS_TASKS";
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "CONSULTANTS_CLIENTS_TASKS" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "CONSULTANTS_CLIENTS_TASKS".* FROM "CONSULTANTS_CLIEN...
```

However, running this other query:

```
select * from CONSULTANTS_CLIENTS_TASKS;
```

gets no errors:

`consultant_name | client_name | task_name | task_date | task_duration | consultant_cost | client_amount | task_cost_related 
-----------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------
(0 rows)`

I haven't mapped all the view's fields in my `.html.erb` but I don't think that's a problem.

So, any ideas on why Rails isn't able to query properly the View? Or why isn't the view properly created?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't it be lowercase `consultants_clients_tasks`?

Comment: Please post thsi as an answer and I'll accept it. That was the issue

Comment: PostgreSQL folds unquoted identifiers to lower case, Rails will quote identifiers behind your back. Your view is called `consultants_clients_tasks` but your code is looking for `"CONSULTANTS_CLIENTS_TASKS"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be lowercase: consultants_clients_tasks?

Answer (score 0):

`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "reports_consultants_clients_tasks" does not exist.`

The error messages seems to suggest that database is missing the table for reports_consultants_clients_tasks. Check db/schemas.rb and see if you have "reports_consultants_clients_tasks"

If you don't maybe you need to migrate the database

`rake db:migrate`